# Safari ITP 2.3: Capped Lifetime For All Script-Writeable Website Data

Tags: safari, service-worker, indexeddb, privacy, cachestorage

I am a little confused about Safari's ITP 2.3 policy which caps the lifetime of script-writable storage in the browser to 7 days.

The official [article](https://webkit.org/blog/9521/intelligent-tracking-prevention-2-3/) states that:

> After seven days of Safari use without the user interacting with a web page on website.example, all of website.example’s non-cookie website data is deleted.

This definitely includes `localStorage`. Does someone know for sure whether

- IndexedDB
- CacheStorage
- Service Worker

are cleared as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the relevant [Webkit commit](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/commit/4db42c1571d821572ea91abe10aedf942b774562), it clearly includes IndexedDB - it does not seem to  include CacheStorage or ServiceWorker.

Answer (score 1):

This post of March 24th lists what is affected.

On that list, I can see IndexDB and something that they call "Service Worker Registrations".

https://webkit.org/blog/10218/full-third-party-cookie-blocking-and-more/